# Find all radio button values

Tags: jquery, html

I want to find all radio button values. But it reurn only one value. My code here.

```
$(document).on("click", ".content>span" , function(e ) {
        var p = $(this).parent('td');
        var RadiobtnValues    = p.find("div").find('input').attr('value');
 });

  <td class="ui-droppable ui-sortable content tbledata">
  <span>
  <img src="images/Close-icon.png" class="close_img">
  <img src="images/expand.png" class="expand_img">
  <div class="form-group" id="radiooption">
        <label>Radio Button</label>             
        <input type="radio" name="radio_0" value="yes">Yes
        <input type="radio" name="radio_0" value="no">No
    </div>
 </span>
 </td>
```

Comment: JQ selector always returns an array of matched elements. You need to either loop through array of radiobuttons or use `.map()` to get all values.

Comment: There's only 1 radio button in your code, please post an example.

Comment: @A.Rama how you mean only one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery's "getter" functions like `attr` only return the value for the first element in the set. If you want all of them, you'll need a loop of some kind. This, for instance, will give you an array of them:

```
var RadiobtnValues    = p.find("div").find('input').map(function() {
    return this.value;
}).get();
```

**Note**: Nothing there is checking whether the radio button(s) in question are selected, this returns their values whether they're selected or not. If you just want the values of the selected ones:

```
var RadiobtnValues    = p.find("div").find('input:checked').map(function() {
    return this.value;
}).get();
```

Or perhaps as an object with the name of each radio button as the key:

```
var RadiobtnValues    = {}
p.find("div").find('input:checked').each(function() {
    RadiobtnValues[this.name] = this.value;
});
```

Comment: Out of interest what's the significance of the `.get()` call?

Comment: @mattytommo: jQuery's `map` (as opposed to JavaScript's) returns a jQuery set wrapped around the values (even though they're not DOM elements, which is what we normally think of jQuery sets containing); `get` converts that into a true array.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this

```
$(document).on("click", ".content>span" , function(e ) {
    var allRadioBoxValues = [];
    var p = $(this).parent('td');
    var RadiobtnValues    = p.find("div").find('input');
    RadiobtnValues.each(function(index,elem){
        allRadioBoxValues.push(elem.value);
    });
    // now 'allRadioBoxValues' will have array of radio button values
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As it says in the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/attr/):

> The .attr() method gets the attribute value for only the first element
>   in the matched set. To get the value for each element individually,
>   use a looping construct such as jQuery's .each() or .map() method.

Which means when you have more elements it will only return the attr of the first. To get all attributes, you could define an array:

```
var RadiobtnValues = new Array();
p.find("div").find('input').each(function(index) { RadiobtnValues[i] = $(this).attr('value') });
```

Comment: It should be `Array()`, not `array()`. And consider using `map`.